# Approximation of Inductive Tensor Product $C(X) \bar{\otimes} C(Y)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces

The following question is from *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory* written by Ronald G. Douglas.

Assume both $X, Y$ are Banach spaces and $X \otimes Y$ is the algebraic tensor product. Let ${X^*}_{\leq1}$ be the closed unit ball in $X^*$. For $w \in X \otimes Y$, define $\|w\|_i = \sup\{\left|\sum_{k = 1}^n \phi(x_k) \psi(y_k)\right| : x_k \in X, y_k \in Y, w = \sum_{k = 1}^n x_k \otimes y_k\}$ (one of $w$'s expression in $X \otimes Y$), $\phi \in {X^*}_{\leq1}, \psi \in {Y^*}_{\leq1}$}. One can check this is a norm on $X \otimes Y$ and we let ($X \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} Y, \| \cdot \|_i$) be the completion of the set ($X \otimes Y, \| \cdot \|_i$).

Now assume $X, Y$ are both compact Hausdorff topological spaces and hence ($C(X), \| \cdot \|_{\infty}$), ($C(Y), \| \cdot \|_{\infty}$) are Banach spaces. Show that ($C(X) \bar{\otimes} C(Y), \| \cdot \|_i$) is isometrically isomorphic to ($C(X \times Y), \| \cdot \|_{\infty}$). Here $X \times Y$ is equipped with the product topology.

Note that any norm $\|\cdot\|$ in $C(X) \oplus C(Y)$ (the direct sum of two Banach Spaces) is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_1$ because both $C(X), C(Y)$ are Banach spaces equipped with $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ (hence $\|(f_x, f_y)\|_1 = \|f_x\|_{\infty} + \|f_y\|_{\infty}$. Meanwhile, one can find a homeomorphism between $C(X)\oplus C(Y)$ and $C(X\times Y)$ because $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \|f_x\|_{\infty} + \|f_y\|_{\infty} \leq 2\|f\|_{\infty}$. Hence I directly start finding relation between ($C(X)\oplus C(Y), \|\cdot\|_1$) and ($C(X) \mathbin{\bar{\otimes}} C(Y), \|\cdot\|_i$)

$$\Large Question Part$$

Say $w \in C(X)\bar{\otimes} C(Y)$ and here I have difficulty finding upper bound of $\|w\|_i$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$. Naively I consider partition of unity of $X$, say {$P_i, i \leq n$} and $\sum_{i \leq n}fP_i$ is one to break down $f$. Hence this could be one of the expression of $f$ part in $w$. I do not know if $n$ is the max number of pieces of $f$ I can break down.

According to hints in the book, by Krein-Milman, it suffices to consider extreme points in $X^*$ and $Y^*$. Before using this, I believe I need to collect enough information of $w$.

Comment: Regarding terminology: I think this is usually called the *injective* tensor product of Banach spaces, not the "inductive" tensor product

Comment: What is $C(X) \times C(Y)$? The cartesian product? If so, it can't be homeomorphic to $C(X \times Y)$. Look at the case where $X$ and $Y$ are finite, the dimensions don't match.

Comment: @NikWeaver I believe your concern is correct. Here I should change the $\times$ to $\oplus$ because I am taking direct sum of two Banach spaces (i,e, ($C(X), \|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and ($C(Y), \|\cdot\|_{\infty}$). When $X$ and $Y$ are finite, dim$C(X)$ = $\vert X \vert$ because in this case $C(X)$ is the span of characteristic function of singleton. Hence dim[$C(X) \oplus C(Y)$] will be equal to dim$C(X \times Y)$.

Comment: @YemonChoi I am confused by the difference between the terminology used in my book and results from Google. These two terms mean the same but in case someone will check the book I will follow what the book is using.

Comment: The vector space dimension of $C(X) \oplus C(Y)$ is the sum of $|X|$ and $|Y|$, the dimension of $C(X\times Y)$ is their product.

Comment: For nice space $X$ and $Y$, $C(X\times Y)=C(X,C(Y))$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Assume both $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets. Let's fix $x_1 \in X$. For any two different $y_i, y_j \in Y$, ($\chi_{\{x_1\}}, \chi_{\{y_i\}}$) is linearly independent with ($\chi_{\{x_1\}}, \chi_{\{y_j\}}$).Then in a basis of $C(X) \oplus C(Y)$, at least we have $\vert Y \vert$ many linearly independent elements. For any two different $x_n, x_m \in X$ and a fixed $y \in Y$, also we have ($\chi_{\{x_n\}}, \chi_{\{y\}}$) is independent with ($\chi_{\{x_m\}}, \chi_{\{y\}}$). If there are no mistakes above, then the basis size of $C(X) \times C(Y)$ will be $\vert X \vert$*$\vert Y \vert$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Now for set bijiection between  $C(X \times Y)$ and $C(X) \oplus C(Y)$, you can refer to this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516784. In $X \times Y$ (equipped with product topology), let $P_x, P_y$(resp.) be projection on $X, Y$(resp.). For any $f \in C(X \times Y)$, I consider the mapping $f \mapsto (f \circ P_x, f \circ P_y)$. The other direction is similar (please check the links for more details).

Comment: You are wrong. Consider the case where $X$ and $Y$ are both singletons.

Comment: @NikWeaver I noticed where my mistake is .... In general your statement is right. When one of $X$ or $Y$ is infinite, $\vert C(X) \oplus C(Y) \vert$ is smaller than $\vert C(X \times Y) \vert$. I made a silly mistake here. $f_x \circ P_x$ is continuous in $X \times Y$ whenever $f_x \in C(X)$ but not the other way.

Comment: No ... no. I really think you should start by trying to understand the finite dimensional case.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @NikWeaver. Now I finally realize when finding basis I should start from leaving all but one coordinate $0$ but I can not imagine I missed this ….